# Connect to QOCI Linux driver in PyQT5?

Tags: linux, oracle, rdbms, pyqt5, oracle-call-interface

When I want to connect my Linux PyQt5 project with QOCI it Shows this message:

> ```
> QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded
> ```

How Can I fix It?

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling..

Comment: Be careful. I think you meant QOCI not QIOC... Maybe you did same typos in your (undisclosed) configurations or/and source code. How can we know.

Answer (score 0):

first look for the available drivers on your linux:

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql
QtSql.QSqlDatabase().drivers()
```

on ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.5 and pyqt5 i only get:

```
['QSQLITE']
```

[in pyqt5 documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html?highlight=qtsql#module-PyQt5.QtSql) i found:

> QtSql contains classes that integrate with SQL databases. It includes editable data models for database tables that can be used with GUI classes. It also includes an implementation of SQLite.

So I suppose, there is only SQLite3 but no Oracle supported in pyqt5. Perhaps you can use python and [cx_oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) instead